# Sumset Borel measurable

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Let $E$ be a Borel set in $\mathbb{R}$. I have the following easy question that hopefully admits an easy answer: Does it follow that $\{(x,y) | (x + y \in E) \}$ is a measurable set in $\mathbb{R}^2$? If so, why?

Answer (score 3):

Your set is $+^{-1}(E)$ and the map $+:\Bbb R^2\to \Bbb R$ is continuous (hence measurable). Therefore, the preimage of a Borel set is measurable. Actually, since continuous maps are Borel functions, your set is a Borel set.